# Fill ComboBox with Function?

Tags: c#, database, combobox

How can i fill comboBox with function while reading its content from sql database using C#

FOR Example

fillcombo("DisplayMamber","ValueMember","ColumnName","TableName");

OR

fillcombo("ColumnName","TableName");

Comment: Do you want just a list of strings, or actual data binding? What have you tried?

Comment: I have used display member,value member property to fill comboBox but i have to write separate code for each comboBox now o wan to get rid of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say where exactly you are stuck, but you should be able to get started with something like this:

```
public static void Bind<T>(ComboBox combo, List<T> Models, string Name, string Value)
    {
        var binding = new BindingSource();

        binding.DataSource = Models;
        combo.DataSource = binding.DataSource;
        combo.DisplayMember = Name;
        combo.ValueMember = Value;
    }
```

Assuming winforms, I have buttons that each have an event like:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    List<State> states = new List<State>();
    using (var dc = new CustomersEntities())
    {
        states = dc.States.ToList();
    }

    Bind<State>(comboBox1, states, "StateName", "Id");
 }
```

This isn't an ideal pattern, but for getting started it would work perfect.

What you might be interested in is something like a generic repository, and building a generic library around it so that you can have methods that look more like:

```
public static void GetCities()
{
    comboBoxCities.Bind<City>(repository.AllCities(), x => x.Name, x.Id);
}
```

but that isn't really covered in a question or two.

Comment: You push me onto the path and your answer helps me a lot in solving my query